# Mobile view not works on SP 2013 site

Tags: view, mobile-view

I have a SP 2013 site. It should be accessable from mobile phones too. It have the mobile view applied by default.

[image]

But if I try to open it from a mobile it is not working (white background and almost nothing appear). The option to switch other views is there and if I choose PC view it works, but not the mobile version. Do you have any idea, what can be wrong or what should I check to get closer to the solution?

Comment: Which kinds of mobile devices? All sites, lists and views, or just this view? Are there any customizations to the master page?

Comment: Yeah it is wrong on all pages and all pages have script editor added. I digged in more to the problem and looks like what I want is to open the site on mobiles in "Full screen UI" mode and not in "Default" or "Mobile" view. And probably I have to add CSS to all pages with @media to customise it to mobile devices, but still not sure. I tought "mobile" view is a view same as PC view just the resolution is optimized for the mobile's screen, but looks like it is to be able to show something without using HTML5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "Mobile View" is just your choice of views to display to mobile devices. You usually create a view with fewer columns, or calculated columns that display more compact versions of the data in other columns.

Keep in mind that many "devices" will not even identify themselves as being a mobile device, and will then get the normal default view.

About the Script Editor web part you mentioned... Views are just pages, and a page with a single list or library web part will display with the usual ribbons. If you add another web part to a page, the ribbons will not display until you click one of the web parts.

SharePoint 2013 supports two kinds of mobile views (for all pages, not just views):

- Append /m to a site URL (not a page URL):  https://yourServer/sites/yourSite/m
- Append ?Mobile=1 to a URL: https://yourServer/sites/yourSite?Mobile=1

These force a mobile view, not auto detect.